# Using OpenGL from the main thread on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

I would like to call a `GLES20` method when an item from the options menu is selected.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.clear:
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

This does not work since I am in the `main` thread and not in `GLThread`. It says:

> call to OpenGL ES API with no current
>   context (logged once per thread)

But what do I have to do to get things working?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer on my own:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.clear:
            // GLSurfaceView.queueEvent
            surface.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                }
            });
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hi matthias,i get the same error on android 3.2.Could you tell when you faced this error with your application?

Comment: @RunO OpenGL and the main application are running in different threads. Therefore you cannot execute OpenGL commands from the main thread (see sourcecode in question). So, being in the main thread,  you have to queue this command to the OpenGL thread (see sourcecode in my answer). I hope this helps. Otherwise start a new question, describe your problem, leave me a link in a comment and I'll see what I can do.