# Screenshot of a TextureView

Tags: android, screenshot, textureview

Is it possible to get a screenshot of an activity containing a texture view showing camera preview and an image over the texture view?
Creating bitmaps resulted in blacked out background screens and could not find any solution for such a case in the previously asked questions.

Or any in built support for getting screenshots of my application activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SurfaceView uses OpenGL thread for drawing and draws directly to a hardware buffer. You have to use glReadPixels.

you can refer this thread :
[Android OpenGL Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731589/android-opengl-screenshot)

i hope this will work for you