# Render Android OpenGL ES 1.0 SurfaceView to JPEG

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, render, surfaceview

I'm trying to render a GLSurfaceView to a JPEG using the following code:

```
FileOutputStream image = FileIO.getInstance().writeFile("racesow/test" + this.frameNum +" .jpg"); // creates an ouputstream in external storage directory
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
this.game.glView.draw(canvas); // glView is the GLSurfaceView
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, image);
image.flush();
image.close();
```

I'm executing this code after the complete scene has been rendered to the surfaceview. The images are being created but they're all black. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just not implemented ([`SurfaceView.draw'1`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/SurfaceView.java#SurfaceView.draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29), [`GLSurfaceView`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java#GLSurfaceView)). Taking screenshots whilst using OpenGL requires special handling, yet the `draw` method is not overridden in `GLSurfaceView`.

However, since it's an open class, you can derive from it and add your own implementation of `draw` with [custom code to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310990/taking-screenshot-of-android-opengl); or whatever suits you best.