# Get view cache from SupportMapFragment (android map v2)

Tags: android

I have a Map in SupportMapFragment and I want to get screenshot from mapview (only visible part of map)

I haven't any idea how i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same question today. Unfortunately it looks like there is no clear cut solution at this time because the v2 map API is using OpenGL ES. Take a look at this post from [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA/Ur4E0BuEKvEJ) and this one from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2)

What I'm going to do is use Googles Static Maps API V2. Here is the link for [Googles Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). This service will satisfy my requirements and hopefully it will work for you as well. Good luck!