# how to get snapshot from Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am wondering to know about how to get snapshot from SupportMapFragment. I have no idea. Please help.

Thanks for your advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to take a screen shot of the fragment View:

```
 View view = findViewById(R.id.fragmentId);
 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
 BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

I haven't tested it.

Comment: It does not work, I tested It, the screenshot output is black.

Comment: @shontauro is right.because we are draw map in google map object.so how i can take screenshot of googlemap with pin,draw route path etc.

Answer (score 2):

To get a drawable you can implement this code:

```
SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
        mapSnapshot = snapshot;
    }
};

googleMap.snapshot(callback);

Drawable screenshot = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),mapSnapshot);
```

If you directly want to save the snapshot on the SD, you can follow this answer:
[Capture screen shot of GoogleMap Android API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2/18308611#18308611)

Answer (score 1):

The [latest update of Google Play Services library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#august_2013) brings us ability to make snapshots via GoogleMap's [snapshot()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#snapshot%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) method.