# Google Map API v.2 - picture of the map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

In my app I'm using `GoogleMap` component to show path on the map. Everything works fine, but I want to save this map with path to the `png`.

Is there any way I can achieve that programatically?

Comment: This is **not possible**. Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2

Comment: endomondo sports tracker using this, so it's possible.

Comment: with v.1 you used to be able to, they dont give out keys anymore for it, now with v.2 you use static maps api to get picture of map

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Static Map API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) and get an image with a path as overlay.

Check the [Paths](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Paths) section in the documentation.