# How can i take/merge screen shot of Google map v2 and layout of xml both programmatically?

Tags: android, screenshot, google-maps-android-api-2

I am taking screenshot of **Google Map v2** by using code of this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18308611/2398886) which is giving me output :

[image]

Which is fine to take screen shot of Map

With following code i can take the screen shot of Layout with black map screen 
 thats ok as with following code Map will black in ScreenShot

```
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/" + "myTestScr" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";
Bitmap bitmap;
        View v1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.rootviewtest);
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        OutputStream fout = null;
        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output of above code:

[image]

What I actually need is:

[image]

So, Now My question that how can get the output like in **3rd** Screen `programmatically`?

Help me to take one screen shot by merging both (1 and 2) screens `programmatically`?

or any other alternate to merge both images `programmatically` after taking both ( 1 and 2 )  screen shots ?

Comment: Please refrain from `using code formatting as emphasis`.  That formatting style is for inline code, not for emphasis.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Call the following method to take the screenshot with map:

```
public void captureMapScreen() {
        SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                try {
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap backBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
                            backBitmap.getConfig());
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/MapScreenShot"
                                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                    bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        mMap.snapshot(callback);

    }
```

`mview` is the root view of your layout and `mMap` is your map fragment.

Make sure that you have the latest `Google Play Services` API.

```
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap backBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
backBitmap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Skip these lines and use `snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);` if you want the screenshot of map only.

Comment: Make sure you are using `android.graphics.Matrix`. and not `android.opengl.Matrix`

Comment: It's worked for me after I change the order of these two 
canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);

Comment: `onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)` is it called on Main Thread?

Comment: in my case I had to add the screen height "getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();" and width "getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();" as the bitmap height and width respectively. Just in case someone was having the same problem. :D

Comment: i am using this method that is work fine take screen shot of map but actually i want in screen shot also marker i am not getting marker in that

Comment: u really made my day <3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Android API, but since you requested "alternate" methods I'll suggest using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). On that site there are several binaries, thus I hope you can download one that suits your system. Otherwise you can download the sources (google around and you'll find many links about building it for Android).

Since I work on a Windows machine I can only tell you how you can invoke it from Windows command-line, but the syntax is similar for other platforms. This app has also a vast selection of APIs for different languages (Java, C or C++ may be of interest for you in particular), so that you can use ImageMagick embedded in your application instead of invoking it from the command line.

Now for the problem at hand: the operation you need to do is to put the "overlay sheet" with symbols over your map, like you'd do with a transparent sheet with drawings over a real map.

So let's call `map.png` and  `overlay.png` the two files to be merged. Note that also the overlay file is a PNG file (more on this later). Then you can obtain something close to what you desire with the following command-line invocation:

```
composite.exe -compose atop overlay.png map.png output.jpg
```

Why must the overlay also be a PNG image? That's because we need an "overlay sheet" that is transparent in most areas (except where you have the balloon tip and the other drawings), but JPG images don't store the transparency information (they don't have the alpha-channel, which stores this information).

So you should modify the part of your code that generates the overlay so as to generate a PNG image with an appropriate alpha channel.

Hope all this helps.