# GoogleMap Android API V2 Capture Error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, screenshot, android-maps-v2

I try @[Tarsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398886/tarsem) answer already but have fatal error occur can I know why?
@[Tarsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398886/tarsem) answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18308611/2398886

**<--- these are my error codes in eclipse: --->**

```
08-21 18:52:23.399: W/dalvikvm(29376): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.testing01.MainActivity2$6

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at com.example.testing01.MainActivity2.CaptureMapScreen(MainActivity2.java:410)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at com.example.testing01.MainActivity2$3.onClick(MainActivity2.java:182)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:867)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

08-21 18:52:23.409: E/AndroidRuntime(29376): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**<--- these are my error codes in eclipse: --->**

**and these are my coding, is it my coding any bug?**

```
public void CaptureMapScreen() 
 {
 SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
             Bitmap bitmap;

             @Override
             public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 bitmap = snapshot;
                 try {
                     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/"
                         + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                         + ".png");

                     // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can customize as per your Requirement

                     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         };

         map.snapshot(callback);

         // myMap is object of GoogleMap +> GoogleMap myMap;
         // which is initialized in onCreate() => 
         // myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_pass_home_call)).getMap();
 }
```

**my Stop Button function:**

```
//End Button Function
 Button timerStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimerStop);      
 timerStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){          

            String latitude3=Double.toString(latitude1);
            String latitude4=Double.toString(latitude2);
            String longitude3=Double.toString(longitude1);
            String longitude4=Double.toString(longitude2);
            String Kcalories=String.format("%.2f", calories);

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NewDataActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat1", latitude3);
            intent.putExtra("lat2", latitude4);
            intent.putExtra("long1", longitude3);
            intent.putExtra("long2", longitude4);
            intent.putExtra("timer", timerStop1);
            intent.putExtra("distance", distance2 + " m");
            intent.putExtra("Ccalories", Kcalories + " kcal");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calories (kcal):" + Kcalories, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(intent);                                          

            try {
                CaptureMapScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //kill task timer and other 
            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        }                

 });
```

Is it my coding have any bug or my logic any probelm?
can anyone help me? thanks :)

Comment: have you add your MainActivity to your manifest file?

Comment: ya, i think so... you means this one right, Piyush?

<activity android:name="com.example.testing01.MainActivity"
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />/activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"android:value="API KEY"/>
<activity android:name=".AddRecord" />
<activity android:name=".UpdateRecord" />
<activity android:name=".DeleteRecord" />
<activity android:name=".ViewRecord" />
<activity android:name=".AddUpdateValues" >

Comment: I try it before if i comment the public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) function then the program can run normally. It will fatal error even the function dont have any code. I still dont know get why ><

Comment: @俊祥李 did you updated Google Play Services to Revision 10 ?

Comment: @Tarsem yes, I testing it on Real Device... Sumsang galaxy mini or S3
...and your means updated the Google play service to revision 10 is the google play service of handphone right?

Comment: no i am asking about the google play services of your SDK

Comment: @Tarsem Yes, I just checked... I use the SDK Manager update before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** Your code to Capture Map Screen is Correct  and if still you have confusion than

**Please Make sure Each Step Below:-**

Below are the steps to capture screen shot of Google Map V2 with example

**Step 1.** open `Android Sdk Manager (Window > Android Sdk Manager)` then `Expand Extras` now `update/install Google Play Services to Revision 10` ignore this step if already `installed`

Read Notes here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#august_2013

**Step 2.**  `Restart Eclipse`

**Step 3.**   `import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback;`

**Step 4.**  Make Method to Capture/Store Screen/image of Map like below

```
public void CaptureMapScreen() 
{
SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bitmap = snapshot;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/"
                        + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ".png");

                    // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can customize as per your Requirement

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        myMap.snapshot(callback);

        // myMap is object of GoogleMap +> GoogleMap myMap;
        // which is initialized in onCreate() => 
        // myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_pass_home_call)).getMap();
}
```

**Step 5.** Now call this `CaptureMapScreen()` method where you want to capture the image

in my case i am `calling this method on Button click in my onCreate()` which is working fine

**like:**

```
Button btnCap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakeScreenshot);
    btnCap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                CaptureMapScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Check Doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#snapshot%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)  and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)

Comment: Sorry about that, can I ask more... the capture screen only the map? If I want capture whole page, can I? 
and the code bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out), the 90 means what? Sometimes I see have other programmer fill 100... Thanks

Comment: its about Quality of image, `quality  Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting `

Comment: Yes, I done it... Do you know how to use Geopoint function? cos I possible change my function to Geopoint function? If any problem can asking you again?

Comment: @俊祥李 see accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309625/how-can-i-take-merge-screen-shot-of-google-map-v2-and-layout-of-xml-both-program to capture whole Page as you asked in your first Comment !

Comment: Here have one problem again, can you help me? Thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394665/how-to-increase-the-accuracy-of-my-start-position

Comment: @Tarsem i have follwed your code and have updated googleplayservices to revision 12 but still I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError for SnapshotReadyCallback, please help