# No Class Definition Found for SnapshotReadyCallback

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, snapshot

I have map & i am trying to get the snapshot of Map on Button click.

```
/**
 * Called when the snapshot button is clicked.
 */
public void onScreenshot(View view) {
    takeSnapshot();
}

private void takeSnapshot() {

    System.out.println("Take SnapShot.......##################");
    if (map == null) {


        return;
    }

    final SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            // Callback is called from the main thread, so we can modify the ImageView safely.
            image.setImageBitmap(snapshot);
        }
    };

        map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                map.snapshot(callback);
            }
        });

}
```

I am getting Error on this line

```
final SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback()
```

The below is my stacktrace.

[image]

Please help i am trying from last two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356878/googlemap-android-api-v2-capture-error).

It seems that maybe you have your google play services api outdated.

**EDIT:**
i.n.e.f has solved it after by adding Google Play Services to Build Path

Comment: i have google play services Rev 15 installed. is it Require More then 15?

Comment: please, update it to the last revision and check if the problem persists

Comment: Google Play services Rev 15 is the Latest version.

Comment: thnx Buddy For your help i have solved it After Adding google play services to Build Path.cheers.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you finally found the solution, I'll edit the answer for future users.