# Layout to bitmap image

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, bitmap, bitmapimage

I am creating an app in which I have 3 ImageViews, 1 EditText and a small map at the corner.
I want to convert the whole screen to a Bitmap.

I am converting it by using this method

```
private Bitmap ConvertToBitmap(LinearLayout layout) {

Bitmap map;

layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

layout.buildDrawingCache();
map=layout.getDrawingCache();
return map;}
```

It is working, but it's not showing the map.
Instead of the map it fills the map area with a black color.
I want to convert the whole screen to a bitmap, including the map.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: If you dont want to show map remove map from xml.

Comment: upload image of layout and image you capture

Comment: Have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309625/how-can-i-take-merge-screen-shot-of-google-map-v2-and-layout-of-xml-both-program?

Comment: http://files.parsetfss.com/fec8ae5e-9978-437c-b9b3-cac83d1377b3/tfss-84330667-3753-4c7e-9099-30358404731f-img.jpg

this is link of image

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta 

Thanks for your reply.. your link is only taking map snapshot but i want whole view including images

Comment: For `convert view to Bitmap`, you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3036736/4186942)