# Capture Google Map v2 View screen shot in Titanium

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing a Titanium app using Google Maps v2. I want to know is there a hook in Ti that allow me to capture mapview as image. I want to take map snap shot at certain point.

I checked in Android documentation and found it's possible: [Capture screen shot of GoogleMap Android API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2/18093295#18093295)

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback.html

Anybody does have knowledge if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Titanium. Simply refer to the UIView, example:

```
var snapshotImgBlog = mapView.toImage(); // OR containerViewOfMapView.toImage()
```

Documentation http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-toImage

If you want to take the snapshot at a certain point on your map, you'll have to position a view on top of the map (can be an empty) at a location *(I'll leave the position/size logic up to you)*, and use that view: `overlayView.toImage()`.