# How to get map view image from lat long in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

In my application user wants to send his  location by searching or touching on map  similar whatsApp after that i want to create a thumbnail of his touch location or search location same as whatsapp.

I searched on internet i found only [this](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) but it is hard to implement with eclipse and android lower versions. So are there any other ways to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18093295/1103584

Comment: @Chris K. it is a for image .I want to create a thumbnail from map of a particular location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dear Montu I think you need a static image of map with respect to coordinate or location, so for it there is a google api please go through it.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

hope this helps...:)

Comment: arigatou gozaimasu :)