# How to take screenshot of selected location using PlacePicker ui widget of android

Tags: android, google-maps, gmsplacepicker

I am using android PlacePicker ui widget in my app. I am able to get the coordinates of selected location. My requirement is also to take screenshot of the selected location. There is no api in PlacePicket widget for screeenshot but GoogleMap api does provide the interface for taking screenshot. 
My question is do I have to implement PlacePicker widget like ui just for taking screenshots ?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this screenshot without using the Place Picker in the Google Places API for Android. What you can use is the [`GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback).

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2), to take a screenshot, implement this line

```
public abstract void onSnapshotReady (Bitmap snapshot)
```

and call

```
public final void snapshot (GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback)
```

For more information, and the sample code, just check the linked SO question.

To know more about Place Picker, check this [link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/using-new-google-places-api-android/).