# App Screenshot?

Tags: android, google-maps, screenshot

I have a Google Map Android Application which I try to capture the screenshot of the whole view together with the map. The screenshot is taken but the Google Map is all black only with the Google logo. I use the following code:

```
private void captureScreen() {
    View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN"
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mapLayout">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context="net.aratos.adc.MapActivity"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.8"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/loadDateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load date" />

    <Button
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/snapshotButton"
        android:text="Snapshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/exportButton"
        android:text="Export PDF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/boundsLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit">

</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also attach the code of the layout.
The output screenshot is the following
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCBGG.png)

After trying Brijesh's code I get the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1haD.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture screen shot of GoogleMap Android API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will help you

```
        googleMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN"
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

---

To Capture Whole Screen 
try following

```
        googleMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            try {
                getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap backBitmap = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
                        backBitmap.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN"
                            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));


                    // Write the string to the file
                    bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("ImageCapture", "FileNotFoundException");
                    Log.d("ImageCapture", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("ImageCapture", "IOException");
                    Log.d("ImageCapture", e.getMessage());
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This code will work but it will only take screenshot of the map. I need to also take screenshot of my whole view.

Comment: Code works. Screenshot is taken with Google Map. The only problem is that the layout below the map is black while it should be white. Any ideas?

Comment: @ManosKardaris The black portion is coming of the snapshot which we are capturing from the **decoreview** we need to adjust the snapshot of the map accordingly so instead of **canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);** try **canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, 0, 100, null);** where 100 can be changed according to your snapshot adjustment.

Comment: Try with this Android library: [QuickShot](https://github.com/Muddz/QuickShot)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GoogleMap.snapshot method to take snapshots of the map ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)))

You will need to implement a

> [GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)

to manage the snapshot taken.

Also, take into account that, according to the documentation:

> **Note:** 
>   Images of the map must not be transmitted to your servers, or
>   otherwise used outside of the application. If you need to send a map
>   to another application or user, send data that allows them to
>   reconstruct the map for the new user instead of a snapshot.

Comment: I do not need the screenshot of the map only but the whole android view together with the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void captureMapScreen() {
    SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            try {
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap backBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
                        backBitmap.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/MapScreenShot"
                                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    mMap.snapshot(callback);

}
```

Make sure to use **android.graphics.Matrix** and not **android.opengl.Matrix**

Hope it helps.