# GoogleMap inside the Recyclerview row

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement where I have to show some location with the map view beside them. So I am planning to Put the Map view inside the row of Recycler view

Doing so will cost some performance issue. As map takes lots of memory. So I am reluctant to do so.

What are other options that I am left with? How can I Achieve that? Please help me in this..... Thanks

Comment: Use [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro?csw=1) ..Show the static map on list and on Click show the actual map with specified location ...

Comment: Google Maps Static APi is free?

Comment: NO .. Read the documentation..

Comment: Then let me know any other solution

Comment: You shoud not put a map view inside list .map view itself is a very complex view involve intense rendering and all that.. you should look for some other option I guess ..maybe have a button to view the map on a new screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) of Google Maps for do what you need:

> Lite mode uses the same classes and interfaces as the full Google Maps
>   Android API. You can set a `GoogleMap` to lite mode in the following
>   ways:
>
> - Either as an `XML` attribute for a `MapView` or `MapFragment`
> - Or in the `GoogleMapOptions` object
>
> As an `XML` attribute for a `MapView` or `MapFragment`
>
> ```
> <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
>     android:id="@+id/map"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     map:cameraZoom="13"
>     map:mapType="normal"
>     map:liteMode="true"/>
> ```
>
> In the `GoogleMapOptions` object
>
> `GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);`

[Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java) is an official example for displaying maps efficiently in `RecyclerView` using lite mode.

Comment: @A.s.ALI Yep. Try it - it exactly for such case.

Comment: how to implement same in iOS

Comment: @A.s.ALI [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) is for Android only. For iOS you can use [ Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro?csw=1) as [ADM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168607/adm) mentioned. Or, if you have complex map (custom markers, fill, path etc.) you can create several screenshots of one `MapView` for each `RecyclerView` row.

Comment: what If i show maps in every Cell of UITable. I am talking about iOS, in android I am going to use elite version of Google maps

Comment: @A.s.ALI Show Static API result (or MapView screenshot) as bitmap whenever you want.

Comment: for some reasons I do not want to user Static API, but screenshot Idea is implementable. Please tell me in detail how I can took screenshot and what you have idea about it

Comment: @A.s.ALI Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093295/6950238) answer.

Comment: This is all about android. All I am concerned now is about iOS

Comment: @A.s.ALI And [that](https://github.com/googlemaps/maps-sdk-for-ios-samples/blob/master/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsDemos/Samples/SnapshotReadyViewController.m)?